# Find lim:$ \lim_{x\to0^+} \ \frac{6(x-\sin(x))\tan(x)}{x^6}\ $

Tags: limits

I am trying to find the limit

$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \ \frac{6(x-\sin(x))\tan(x)}{x^6}\
$$

and $$
\lim_{x\to0^-} \ \frac{6(x-\sin(x))\tan(x)}{x^6}\
$$

I'm not sure that either one exists or not because it looks to be oscillating as $x$ approaches $0$. And if they do not exist, how would I prove that?

Comment: Do you know about series? The $(\tan x)/x$ part does safely to $1$, so we are looking at $(x-\sin x)/x^6$. This blows up, look at the Maclaurin series of $\sin x$. Could the question be about $x-x^3/6-\sin x$ instead of $x-\sin x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be computed as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{6(x-\sin (x))\tan (x)}{x^{6}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow
0}\frac{(x-\sin (x))}{x^{3}}\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}\cdot
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{6}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1\cdot (+\infty
)=+\infty .
\end{equation*}
I have used
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x-\sin (x))}{x^{3}}\overset{H}{=}%
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3x^{2}}\overset{H}{=}\frac{1}{6}%
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} &=&\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{6}. \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}\left. =\right. \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}%
\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\cos x}\left. =\right.
1\cdot 1 &=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents:
$$x-\sin x=\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3),\enspace\text{hence}\enspace x-\sin x\sim_0 \frac{x^3}6$$.
As $\tan x\sim_0 x$, we have:
$$\frac{6(x-\sin x)\tan x}{x^6}\sim_0\frac{x^4}{x^6}=\frac 1{x^2},$$
so that the limit is $+\infty$.